# PHP fwrite deletes as much characters as it adds

Tags: php, fwrite

I've got a piece of PHP code that's supposed to find an appropriate line in a txt file and replace it with a new value. Everything works as long as the length of a string doesn't change. If it's one character longer, the following line gets one character deleted and so on. I have no clue how to fix it. Also I didn't include the part that searches for the right line, it works alright and I don't think it's relevant.
PHP code:

```
$f = fopen("score.txt", "r+") or die("error");
$s = $_SESSION["id"].";".$_POST['S']."\n";
(...)
fwrite($f,$s);
fclose($f);
```

TXT file before:

```
N01;99
N02;102
N03;11
```

TXT file after changing the value for N01 to 100 (one character longer):

```
N01;100
02;102
N03;11
```

Comment: Think of a file as a piece of graph paper with one character per square. You can't write 3 squares of new data over 2 squares of existing data in the middle without either overwriting another square, rewriting everything after the insertion, or rewriting the entire page. The simplest thing to do in this case is to remove the original file and write a new one with changes in its place. `fopen()` with the `w` mode will do this.

Comment: Since you're looking to go line-by-line, consider writing lines to a *separate*, temporary file, then replacing the original once you're done modifying things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to a file, you're just overwriting bytes. There's no way to insert and delete directly into a file.

What you need to do is read the whole file into memory, replace what you want, then write it all back to the file.

You can use the `file()` function to read the file into an array, where each element is one line of the file.

```
$lines = file("score.txt");
foreach ($lines as &$line) {
    list ($id, $s) = explode(';', $line);
    if ($id == $_SESSION['id']) {
        $line = $_SESSION["id"].";".$_POST['S']."\n";
        break;
    }
}
file_put_contents("score.txt", implode('', $lines));
```